# How to count rows based on column value?

Tags: php, mysql, count

Using PHP and MySQL, I have a table that holds check in data for customers: the month and year they checked in.

```
ID  Month   Year

1   01      2015
1   01      2015
4   01      2015
1   03      2015
4   03      2015
1   05      2015
```

I need a total count of rows per month and year. So in this example I should get a total of 3 for id 1 for the month of 01 and year 2015. I'm adding the total days a person checked in for each month of each year.

Having a problem getting started with the code. I assume I can do this with MySQL `count` or something.

Comment: This is called a `group by`.  It is a fundamental part of the SQL language.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work with PHP. Will post back. btw error in my question. I should get two for id 1. Can't seem to get the count for each month 1-12 of each year. Still at it...

Answer (score 0):

you can using mysql function are "GROUP BY

select count(id) from table group by year

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL COUNT() function with GROUP BY like:

```
  SELECT ID, Month, Year, COUNT(*)
    FROM checked_customer
    GROUP BY ID, Month, Year;
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong, you are grupping by id+month+year, but user3366802 is going to group only by year+month

Comment: Without the WHERE clause, I get the correct results. But adding it, I get only one month's worth of results. Why?<br><br>
mysql_select_db($database_MySQLconnection, $MySQLconnection);
$query_rsCheckin = "SELECT guestID, month, year, COUNT(month) FROM checkin WHERE guestID = 4988 GROUP BY month, year" ;
$rsCheckin = mysql_query($query_rsCheckin, $MySQLconnection) or die(mysql_error());$row_rsCheckin = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCheckin);
$totalRows_rsCheckin = mysql_num_rows($rsCheckin);<br><br>
while($row_rsCheckin = MySQL_fetch_assoc($rsCheckin)){ echo row_rsCheckin['guestID'] ...['month'], etc